# Export a PHP/MYSQL database, table by table

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays, backup

I am trying to save a array of tables into separate file. Why doesn't this code work?

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'pessoa_Out.txt' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'       LINES TERMINATED BY '#' FROM $tables[$i]";
?>
```

I have already tried to save a single table and I was successful. I can also list the array values, so the problem must be on this line.

Comment: What's the error? Could it be a permissions issue (i.e. can the process write to that file?)

Comment: $query="SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'pessoa_Out.txt' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '#' FROM $tables[$i]";

Comment: this is the code sorry i forgot to put it in the main question

Comment: I take it that its in a loop and the SQL is overwriting the text file each time? OR that you have an array reference inside a string. FROM $tables[$i]"; -> FROM".$tables[$i];

Comment: if i try to backup a single table i am sucessfull. But if i try to save all the tables within a database its impossible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sql is in a loop then you are overwriting the file each time. Also placing variables inside string is not advisable as arrays don't evaluate unless you use curly brackets too!

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($tables);$i++)
{
    $query = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '".$tables[$i]."_Out.txt' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'       LINES TERMINATED BY '#' FROM ".$tables[$i];
    mysqli_query($query);
}
?>
```